# Can I use LongText instead of varchar

Tags: mysql, varchar

I want to store string like

```
ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405,ins37_14387771184402,ins37_14387771184403,ins37_14387771184404,ins37_14387771184405
```

When set DATATYPE `varchar(255)` it displays

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'tids' at row 1

And string not fully stored,

So can i use `LONGTEXT` datatype

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you could consider adding a new table to store this values as single records bound to a foreign key. (?)

Comment: Why don't you store this information vertical? You could have problems in the future when you'll try to get this information because is *denormalized*.

Comment: As others have indicated, consider normalizing your data

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a rough idea of the expected max length?

varchar(X) is limited to 255 character before MySQL 5.0.3 and 65k at most with MySQL 5.0.3 [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Text data type should be big enough.

You should also consider an update of your data model as suggested by @oNare

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to do with this value *after* you've stored it?

If you're only ever going to retrieve *the whole thing* in one go, based on some *other* value in the record, then you can increase it to one of the TEXT types.

If you're intending to do *any* kind of filtering based on the value(s) in this field then this is absolutely *not* the way to go.
Repeated values in a single field is one of *the* most basic NO-NO's on Planet Database.